# Interpolation of Singular Functions

Tags: interpolation

I am trying to interpolate discontinuous functions for `R` in interval $[0,100]$ and `r` in interval $[0,100]$:

```
(1/R-r)EllipticK[r/(R-r)^2]
```

The resultant function is a good fit except near singularities, where it often gives indeterminate values, even when the original function is not indeterminate.

I have tried using Spline and Hermite methods to no avail. Changing the order of interpolation does not seem to help either.

Can anyone offer advice on how to interpolate this function successfully?

Comment: Split the data into two regions (r > R or not), interpolate the regions separately, and combine them with a `Piecewise` function: `Piecewise[{{interpolationfunction1, r > R}, {interpolationfunction2, r < R}}, Indeterminate]`

Comment: Gee, Thanks for help.